# Python Pytest ignore tests from a directory mentioned in the setup.cfg file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to use pytest to run some tests. My package contains a setup.cfg file where I've stated all the pytest options

`[tool:pytest]
 addopts =
 --verbose
 unit`

as it is visible I've added the `unit` directory to find the test files. This works fine and all the tests from the directory get executed during the normal build process.

**Actual Problem** -

Now I have another directory `integ` where I have my integration tests which I want to run sometimes but do not want them as a part of my build process. I have created another command line option to run my integ tests but I am not able to figure out how to provide the file set correctly for the same

I've tried `pytest --ignore=unit integ` through command line but it runs all my tests from unit as well as integ. I want to run the tests present in integ only and ignore the tests from unit. What am I missing here?

[update]
When I run `pytest --ignore=unit/test_file.py integ` it ignores the tests in test_file but when I use `pytest --ignore=unit/*.py integ` it says `no matches found: --ignore=test/*.py`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--override-ini=testpaths=test_integ` solved my problem. I was able to override the options from my setup.cfg file using this.